# MVC5 HTML make column as table header?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, pivot

Look at this table in my database:

```
==============================
|^student |^Subject |^Result |
==============================
| name1   | math    | pass   |
==============================
| name1   | physics | pass   |
==============================
| name1   | Biology | faille |
==============================
| name2   | math    | pass   |
==============================
| name2   | physics | faille |
==============================
| name2   | Biology | pass   |
==============================
```

By using MVC 5, HTML and SQL Server 2017 can I make it like this in index page:

```
======================================
|^student | Math | Physics | Biology |
======================================
| name1   | pass | pass    | faille  |
======================================
| name2   | pass | faille  | pass    |
======================================
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure. Pivot, or group by, or pick your poison. Please be more specific and detailed, because how you do it depends on your consumer - stored proc, entity framework, or some other ORM, or plain queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select student,
    max(case when subject = 'math'    then result end) math,
    max(case when subject = 'physics' then result end) physics,
    max(case when subject = 'biology' then result end) biology
from mytable
group by student
```